# How can I change an React.Node's props based on another prop

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm using `prop-types` to check the type and set defaults to my components props. One of my props is a color for a React.Node that displays an SVG image.

```
Rating.defaultProps = {
  iconColor: '#E5C100',
  iconFull: <StarSharp />
  iconEmpty: <StarBorderSharp />
  iconHalfFull: <StarHalfSharp />
}
Rating.propTypes = {
  iconColor: Proptypes.string,
  iconFull: Proptypes.Node,
  iconEmpty: Proptypes.Node,
  iconHalfFull: Proptypes.Node
};
```

I want to pass on the `iconColor` as a `style={color: this.props.iconColor}` inside my render method, but I'm not sure how. I have tried searching for an answer, but I cannot seem to find one.

Comment: Can you include code for your current render method implementation (or just the relevant part)?

Comment: This is the only relevant part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should be able to compute the style by first checking for a valid `iconColor` in your component's `props` and then falling back to the default `iconColor` prop provided by `Rating.defaultProps` if needed.

To illustrate this technique, consider the following:

```
class Rating extends React.Component {

 render() {

    // If iconColor is undefined/falsey in this components props, then
    // fallback to the default iconColor prop as specified in the
    // Rating.defaultProps object
    const style = { 
       color : (this.props.iconColor || Rating.defaultProps.iconColor) 
    };

    // Return your JSX as needed, with locally computed style object
    return (<div style={ style }>
       ...
    </div>)
 }
}

Rating.defaultProps = {
  iconColor: '#E5C100',
  iconFull: <StarSharp />
  iconEmpty: <StarBorderSharp />
  iconHalfFull: <StarHalfSharp />
}

Rating.propTypes = {
  iconColor: Proptypes.string,
  iconFull: Proptypes.Node,
  iconEmpty: Proptypes.Node,
  iconHalfFull: Proptypes.Node
};
```

Comment: You do understand the question correctly and the solution does work in this situation. I do which there was a way to update React.Nodes directly when they are inside of a variable rather than relying on CSS inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do without relying on CSS inheritance:

```
 const iconFull = React.cloneElement(props.iconFull, {'style': props.iconStyles});
 const iconEmpty = React.cloneElement(props.iconEmpty, {'style': props.iconStyles});
 const iconHalfFull = React.cloneElement(props.iconHalfFull, {'style': props.iconStyles});
```

I changed the prop from `iconColor` (string) to `iconStyles` (object) to make the it into a broader feature